# How to compute the confidence intervals on regression coefficients in PLS?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, latent-variable, partial-least-squares

The underlying model of [PLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) is that a given $n \times m$ matrix $X$ and $n$ vector $y$ are related by 
$$X = T P' + E,$$
$$y = T q' + f,$$
where $T$ is a latent $n \times k$ matrix, and $E, f$ are noise terms (sssuming $X, y$ are centered).

PLS produces estimates of $T, P, q$, and a 'shortcut' vector of regression coefficients, $\hat{\beta}$ such that $y \sim X \hat{\beta}$. I would like to find the distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ under some simplifying assumptions, which should probably include the following:

1. The model is correct, *i.e.* $X = T P' + E,y = T q' + f$ for unknown $T, P, q$;
2. The number of latent factors, $k$, is known, and used in the PLS algorithm;
3. The actual error terms are i.i.d. zero-mean normal with known variances;

This question is somewhat underdefined because there are scores of variants of 'the' PLS algorithm, but I would accept results for any of them. I would also accept guidance on how to estimate the distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ via *e.g.* a bootstrap, but perhaps that is a separate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you know this article: [PLS-regression: a basic tool of chemometrics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169743901001551) ([PDF](http://libpls.net/publication/PLS_basic_2001.pdf))? Deriving SE and CI for the PLS parameters is described in §3.11.

I generally rely on Bootstrap for computing CIs, as suggested in e.g., Abdi, H. [Partial least squares regression and projection on latent structure regression (PLS Regression)](http://www.utdallas.edu/%7Eherve/abdi-wireCS-PLS2010.pdf). See also the [plspm](https://github.com/gastonstat/plspm) package, and its accompagnying texbook: [PLS Path Modeling with R](https://www.gastonsanchez.com/PLS_Path_Modeling_with_R.pdf).

I seem to remember there are theoretical solutions discussed in Tenenhaus M. (1998) *La régression PLS: Théorie et pratique* (Technip), but I cannot check for now as I don't have the book. For now, there are some useful R packages, like [plsRglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plsRglm/index.html).

*P.S.* I just discovered Nicole Krämer's work, in reference to the [plsdof](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plsdof/index.html) R package.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a paper by Reiss, *et. al.*, 
[Partial least squares confidence interval calculation for industrial end-of-batch quality prediction](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemolab.2009.11.003), in which appears the quote:

> The PLS prediction should be accompanied by an online conﬁdence
>   interval to indicate the accuracy of the prediction. The formulation of
>   the conﬁdence interval for the PLS prediction is an area of study that
>   has not concluded a “gold standard”.

This paper contains a reference to the 'excellent survey of such work', [Standard error of prediction for multiway PLS](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0169-7439%2801%2900204-0), by Faber and Bro, and a paper by Faber and Kowalski, 
[Propagation of measurement errors for the validation of predictions obtained by principal component regression and partial least squares](http://http%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2Fdoi%3A10.1002%2F%28SICI%291099-128X%28199705%2911%3A3%3C181%3A%3AAID-CEM459%3E3.0.CO%3B2-7).
I will summarize these results as they become available...

Comment: (+1) Good to know, thanks. I should look again in Michel Tenenhaus's work -- I'll let you know if I find sth interesting.