# Prediction interval in principal component regression

Tags: regression, pca, prediction-interval

I would like to obtain a prediction interval from a model returned by the R package [pls](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/index.html). The `predict` method does not seem to be able to return this value. I wonder if anyone has a suggested solution?

Comment: The `pls` package doesn't seem to offer this opoortunity, but [Principal Components Regression: Transform 95% CIs back to original space](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86378/930) discusses the issue of PCR and confidence intervals, and [How to compute the confidence intervals on regression coefficients in PLS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5364/930) that of PLS.